# Possibility to object to closing?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

After a question get closed, it can be reopened after it was substantially enhanced.

But it may be substantially enhanced while it has one or more close votes, but not closed yet.

I think it should be possible to get the close votes removed in case there is a majority that it should be reopened if it were closed.
Some close votes mean a question is only partially closed. Now, few or just one vote could close it. I think partly closing should be reverted if it would be voted to reopen when completely closed.

Is this possible?
If not, is it a helpful feature?